# gam: choosing between cubic and thin-plate splines

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I am using gam (mgcv) to model a continuous response (a soil nutrient) in relation to a continuous predictor plus categorical predictors plus site random effects (modest number of sites) with:

```
    gam(log(y) ~ s(x, bs = "cr", by = fac1) + 
              fac1 + fac2 + s(site, bs = "re", by = flag), 
        method = "REML")
```

The data come from a landscape study where sampling was challenging (to say the least), so the number of samples is small and the coverage of the range of x values is quite patchy in the upper part of the range.

Use of a cubic spline for x, as above, results in quite a different shape for the fitted function compared to the default thin-plate spline for that part of the space where x values are sparse. However, both models have almost identical results in terms of deviance explained and pattern of residuals. The shape of the function produced by the cubic spline is much preferred by my colleagues who conducted the study because they feel they can reconcile it with theory more readily than the alternative. However, I am wondering if:

- there are other criteria that I can investigate to choose between the models?
- any theoretical reason to choose between using "cr" or "tp" for a univariate smooth with patchy data?

**Update: plots of the alternative models**

[image: GAM using bs = "cr"]

[image: GAM using bs = "tp"]

Comment: Can you include PNGs of the two fitted functions? Thin-plate splines have the edge in terms of MSE over the cubic regression spline, but are much more costly to set up the basis function for. I'd be interested to see whether the effects of the two splines are really that different given the uncertainty in their estimation at end points of a variable, esp if the data is patchy.

Comment: Is `x` roughly normally distributed? If it isn't and it make ecological.environmental sense, log transform it. Do look at `gam.check()` for both models and confirm that the test for the size of the original basis dimension doesn't indicate that the default was too small. Also look at the plots for both models produced by this function to see if there are any differences in the residuals etc. You no longer need the `by = flag` trick in `gam()` to turn off a random effect: look at arguments `term` and `exclude` to achieve the same thing in `?predict.gam`

Comment: Finally, without any further info, it would be cherry picking to choose the type of spline basis (i.e. the model) simply because your colleagues prefer one output better than the other. If you end up having no objective reason to select one basis type over the other and your models are otherwise OK, you have a responsibility to present both and to proceed with interpreting both. It would be technically unsound and ethically dubious to cherry pick a model over another just because it gave you/them results they preferred.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - Thanks. I've added plots showing predictions from the two models. The two sets of residuals are almost identical and seem well-behaved as judged with `qqplot` and graphing against fitted values and predictors. `gam.check` showed that EDFs were well below k' values. Unfortunately, the x variable has only a small number of unique values (18) so there's not much room for adjustment above the default k=10. I agree with your view that the best course is to present both results, assuming both survive scrutiny here.

Comment: After canvassing opinions from a number of others, it's been decided to go with the thin-plate regression spline fit on the basis (no pun intended) of parsimony.

Comment: Yup, the CRS fit for group 1 are crazy; there seems no reason for them to take a unimodal shape.